# Magento 2.3 - How to setup LEMP - Multi Website Localhost url setup on Nginx

Tags: magento2.3.3, nginx, localhost, centos, linux

For testing, we using Magento 2.3.4 in localhost [Centos 7 & Nginx]

Main-store Path & URL:

**Path :** usr/share/nginx/html/gomart - **URL :**  http:// 192.168.1.64:8077/

Multi-Store URL :

**Path :** usr/share/nginx/html/gomart/grocery - **URL :**  http:// 192.168.1.64:8077/grocery/

How to setup Multi-Website url into **=>** nginx.conf.sample **&** index.php **&** .htaccess